# B737-800 wire routing path diagrams

Tags: boeing-737, routing

I was wondering from where can I get screenshots of the aircraft internal fuselage without wall or ceiling panels showing the manufacturer wirebundle routes and ground terminal blocks like the pic attached.
I searched the IPC, WDM and AMM with no luck.
Lets say I want to get a screenshot as attached from station 360 to station 580 but for the left side of the aircraft, which manual should I check, if not within any manuals where can I get it ?

[image: wire route example]